# How to configure emacs for use with yarn 3?

Tags: javascript, lsp

The yarn package manager suggests a [snippet](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#emacs) of elisp to use:

> Create a .dir-locals.el with the following content to enable Flycheck
> and LSP support and make sure LSP is loaded after local variables are
> applied to trigger the eval-after-load:

```
((typescript-mode
  . ((eval . (let ((project-directory (car (dir-locals-find-file default-directory))))
                (setq lsp-clients-typescript-server-args `("--tsserver-path" ,(concat project-directory ".yarn/sdks/typescript/bin/tsserver") "--stdio")))))))
```

When I create the `.dir-locals.el` file and open it I see the following warning:

```
‘(typescript-mode (eval let ((project-directory (car (dir-locals-find-file default-directory)))) (setq lsp-clients-typescript-server-args `("--tsserver-path" ,(concat project-directory ".yarn/sdks/typescript/bin/tsserver") "--stdio"))))’ is a malformed function
```

Is this a malformed function?

If so then in what way is it malformed?

Major modes:

```
Emacs-Lisp, ElDoc
```

Enabled minor modes:

```
Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Company Counsel-Projectile Delete-Selection Diff-Hl Diff-Hl-Flydiff
Drag-Stuff Drag-Stuff-Global Editorconfig Electric-Indent
File-Name-Shadow Flycheck Font-Lock Global-Auto-Revert Global-Company
Global-Diff-Hl Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit
Global-Hl-Line Global-Page-Break-Lines Global-Undo-Tree Ivy Key-Chord
Line-Number Linum Magit-Auto-Revert Mouse-Wheel Page-Break-Lines
Projectile Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Smartparens Smartparens-Global
Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree Volatile-Highlights Which-Key Yas
Yas-Global
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: It is not a function at all, but when you *look* at this in a buffer, you should not get any warning: it's just text (unless you are running something like `flycheck` or similar). If you try to *evaluate* this, then you should get an "illegal function" error, since you are trying to call something which is not a function. What's the buffer that contains this code when you look at it and what major/minor modes are enabled on it? Do `C-h m` to find out and edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  Yes, I'm running `flycheck`.